# curl command into Java - encoding xml file

Tags: java, rest, curl, url-encoding

I have what I believe is a simple curl command that I'm trying to turn into appropriate Java code, to put into my Java-based app. The curl command is like this:

curl -d command=setUserItem  -d data_action=replace --data-urlencode user@user.xml --data-urlencode vfs_items@vfs_items.xml https://www.example.com/

Note it involves two xml flat files... When I invoke curl from the folder that contains those files... I get back a good response, that is an xml that has a few tags that lets me know it processed the command okay, and it creates a user as it should.

Below is my Java code. My feeling is that i'm not doing the part of handling the xml files's content correctly... I try just putting it into a string, but no luck. When I invoke through Java.... I get back a "bad" response indicating i'm not calling it correctly.

```
    String xmlUser, xmlVfsItems, xmlPermissions;
    String urlStr;
    String[] paramName;
    String[] paramVal;

    xmlUser = "" + 
    "       <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <user type=\"properties\"> " +
    "       <password>web</password> " +
    "       <version>1.0</version> " +
    "       <root_dir>/</root_dir> " +
    "       <userVersion>6</userVersion> " +
    "       </user> " +
    "";
    xmlVfsItems = "" + 
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> " +
    "<vfs_items type=\"vector\"> " +
    "<vfs_items_subitem type=\"properties\"> " +
    "<name>curl_user</name> " +
    "<path>/</path> " +
    "<vfs_item type=\"vector\"> " +
    "<vfs_item_subitem type=\"properties\"> " +
    "<url>FILE://Users/ftp_accounts/curl_user/</url> " +
    "</vfs_item_subitem> " +
    "</vfs_item> " +
    "</vfs_items_subitem> " +
    "</vfs_items> " +
    "";


    urlStr = "https://www.example.com/";
    paramName = ["command", "data_action","user", "vfs_items"];
    paramVal = ["setUserItem", "replace", xmlUser, xmlVfsItems];

    httpPost(urlStr, paramName, paramVal);



String httpPost(String urlStr, String[] paramName, String[] paramVal) throws Exception {
      URL url = new URL(urlStr);
      HttpURLConnection conn =
          (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setUseCaches(false);
      conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      // Create the form content
      OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
      Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
      for (int i = 0; i < paramName.length; i++) {
        writer.write(paramName[i]);
        writer.write("=");
        writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(paramVal[i], "UTF-8"));
        writer.write("&");
      }
      writer.close();
      out.close();

      if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
      }

      // Buffer the result into a string
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
      }
      rd.close();

      conn.disconnect();
      println(sb.toString());
      return sb.toString();
    }
```

This is the good response I get from curl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result><response_status>OK</response_status>    <response_type>text</response_type>
<response_data></response_data></result>
```

The web-service involes creating a user within the CrushFTP system, and I can also verify the new user is created.

Here's the "bad response" I get from java... It looks like it is presenting the webpage as if I had accessed the url through a browser... the user-record it is suppose to create is not created:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>    <head>        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />        <title>CrushFTP WebInterface</title>        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/WebInterface/jQuery/css/login.css" />        <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebInterface/Resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebInterface/jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebInterface/jQuery/js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebInterface/Resources/js/login.js"></script>                <script type="text/javascript">        function showRecaptcha(element) {        if(window.Recaptcha)        {        window.Recaptcha.create("/*RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY*/", element, {        theme: "red"        });        }        }        $(document).ready(function() {                /*RECAPTCHA*/            });        var passwordRule = {random_password_length:6,min_password_numbers:0,min_password_lowers:0,min_password_uppers:0,min_password_specials:0};        </script>        <script></script>    </head>    <body style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;" class="login">                <div id="login">            <div id="languageSelector" style="display:none;">                <select>                    <option value="en" rel="English">English</option>                    <option value="cn" rel="Chinese">Chinese</option>                    <option value="cs" rel="Czech">Czech</option>                    <option value="da" rel="Danish">Danish</option>                    <option value="nl" rel="Dutch">Dutch</option>                    <option value="fr" rel="French">French</option>                    <option value="de" rel="German">German</option>                    <option value="hu" rel="Hungarian">Hungarian</option>                    <option value="it" rel="Italian">Italian</option>                    <option value="pl" rel="Polish">Polish</option>                    <option value="sk" rel="Slovak">Slovak</option>                    <option value="es" rel="Spanish">Spanish</option>                    <option value="se" rel="Swedish">Swedish</option>                </select>            </div>            <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="/" onSubmit="return doLogin2();">                <div id="panelbody">                    <div id="branding" class="clearfix branding">                        <img id="loginWheel" src="/WebInterface/images/wheel.gif" />                        <a id="defaultLogoLink" href="http://www.crushftp.com/">                            <img id="imgLogo" src="/WebInterface/images/logo.png" style="border-width:0px;float:left;" />                        </a>                    </div>                    <div id="panelLogin">                        <div>                            <label id="UserNameText">Username</label>                            <input autocomplete="on" type="text" class="textbox" name="username" id="username" value="" />                        </div>                        <div>                            <label id="PasswordText">Password</label>                            <input type="password" class="textbox" name="password" id="password" value="" />                        </div>                        <div id="rememberMePanel">                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" /> <span id="RememberMeText">Remember Me</span></label>                        </div>                        <div style="clear:both;height:1px;padding:0px;margin:0px;"></div>                        <div id="recaptcha_div"></div>                        <div style="clear:both;height:1px;padding:0px;margin:0px;"></div>                        <div class="submit clearfix">                            <input type="submit" value="login" style='display:none;' />                            <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login" />                            <input type="hidden" name="skip_login" value="true" />                            <input type="hidden" name="encoded" value="false" />                            <input type="submit" value="login now" style="position:absolute;left:-1000px;top:-1000px;" />                            <a class="button" id="btnLogin" href="javascript:void(0);">                                <span id="LoginButtonText">Login</span>                            </a>                        </div>                        <p class="lostpassword">                            <a href="javascript:emailPassword();" id="ForgotPasswordLinkText">I forgot my password, email it to me.</a>                        </p>                    </div>                </div>            </form>            <form id="changePassForm" method="post" target="dummyIframe" action="/WebInterface/function/" onSubmit="doLogin();">                <div id="changepasswordPanel" style="display:none;margin-bottom:10px;">                    <div class="clearfix branding" style="clear:both;">                        <a id="defaultLogoLink" href="http://www.crushftp.com/">                            <img id="imgLogo" src="/WebInterface/images/logo.png" style="border-width:0px;float:left;margin:3px 0px 10px 0px;" />                        </a>                    </div>                    <h2 class="popupHeader" style="clear:both;margin-top:15px;" id="ChangePasswordHeaderText">                    Change your password                    </h2>                    <div class="passwordChangeNote" id="ChangePasswordNoteText">                        You must change your password to continue                    </div>                    <div class="buttonPanel">                        <label for="current_password" id="CurrentPasswordText">Current Password:</label>                        <input id="current_password" class="textbox" type="password" />                        <br />                        <br />                        <label for="new_password1" id="NewPasswordText">New Password:</label>                        <input id="new_password1" class="textbox" type="password" />                        <br />                        <br />                        <label for="new_password2" id="ConfirmPasswordText">Confirm Password:</label>                        <input id="new_password2" class="textbox" type="password" />                        <div style="text-align:right;margin-top:10px;">                            <a id="btnChangePasswordCancel" class="button" href="javascript:void(0);">                                <span id="CancelButtonText">Cancel</span>                            </a>                            <a id="btnChangePassword" class="button" href="javascript:void(0);">                                <span id="ChanngePasswordButtonText">Change Password</span>                            </a>                        </div>                        <div style="clear:both"></div>                        <div class="spacing">                            <br />                            <hr />                            <br />                        </div>                        <div>                            <a id="btnGeneratePassword" class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" style="float:left">                                <span id="GeneratePasswordButtonText">Generate password</span>                            </a>                            <div id="passwordGeneratePanel" style="display:none;">                                <br />                                <br />                                <input id="generated_password" type="text" class="textboxSmall" style="float:left;" />                                <a id="usePassword" class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" style="float:left">                                    <span id="GeneratePasswordUseButtonText">Use this</span>                                </a>                                <a id="cancelPassword" class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" style="float:left">                                    <span id="GeneratePasswordCancelButtonText">Cancel</span>                                </a>                            </div>                            <div style="clear:both"></div>                        </div>                    </div>                </div>            </form>        </div>        <div id="OTPBox" style="display:none;">            <img class="closeButton" alt="close" src="/WebInterface/jQuery/images/cancel.png"            onclick="$.unblockUI();"/>            <h2 class="popupHeader" id="OTPDialogHeaderText">            Enter your OTP here            </h2>            <div class="buttonPanel">                <div style="width:100%;">                    <input id="otp" type="password" style="width:95%;padding:5px;" />                </div>                <br />                <br />                <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 10px;">                    <button id="btnSubmitOTP">                    <span id="OTPSubmitButtonText">Submit</span>                    </button>                </div>            </div>        </div>        <div id="olderBrowserNotice" style="display:none;top:100px;padding: 10px;" class="alertMessage">            <div id="OldBrowserNoticeHTMLAsText">                Your browser is out of date, it was released almost a decade ago! As a result it is very slow, full of bugs, and this WebInterface may or may not even work with IE6.                <br />                <br />                <div style="text-align:right;">                    <button id="proceedAnyway">Proceed Anyway Cautiously</button>or get a better browser : &nbsp;                    <a href="http://chrome.google.com/">Chrome</a> | <a href="http://www.getfirefox.com/">FireFox</a>                </div>            </div>        </div>                <iframe id="dummyIframe" name="dummyIframe" src="javascript:false;" style="display:none;"></iframe>    </body></html>
```

Comment: please include the response

Comment: Added the responses to original question.

Comment: Try adding an accept header to the request like `Accept: */*`.

Answer (score 0):

I "dumbed down" the question to post it here, and I mistakenly omitted a key part... The part that was actually causing my problem... The URL also had a username/password, which I needed to turn into a Authorization: header with the credentials BASE64 encoded.

Thanks all for responding... the mention about the header got me thinking about it.